# Using Rust libraries reqwest and select in conjunction

Tags: select, rust, reqwest

I am trying to follow the example here:
https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/web/scraping.html, which utilizes both Reqwest and Select in order to get an html response then parse the data.

I am using Reqwest version 0.10.4 and Select version 0.4.3 which are the versions it shows in the example.  However, I am getting an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `reqwest::Response: std::io::Read` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:25
   |
19 |     Document::from_read(res)?
   |                         ^^^ the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `reqwest::Response`
   | 
  ::: /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/select-0.4.3/src/document.rs:31:25
   |
31 |     pub fn from_read<R: io::Read>(mut readable: R) -> io::Result<Document> {
   |                         -------- required by this bound in `select::document::Document::from_read`
```

It seems like the from_read method takes in a Read type but the reqwest::get method returns a different type.  Is there some sort of conversion that must be done first before the response is passed to the from_read method?

This is the example:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate error_chain;
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate select;

use select::document::Document;
use select::predicate::Name;

error_chain! {
   foreign_links {
       ReqError(reqwest::Error);
       IoError(std::io::Error);
   }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let res = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/").await?;

    Document::from_read(res)?
        .find(Name("a"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("href"))
        .for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reqwest::get` returns a `Result<Response>`, then with the `?` you are unwrapping the `Result`, meaning you now have a `Response` object as documented [here](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.4/reqwest/struct.Response.html). And because a web call can successfully occur but still fail (see HTTP non 200 codes) you *should* check the response code, but since this is to learn we'll ignore it. What you want is a struct that implements the `std::io::Read` trait, reading up on that shows that `String` implements that trait. Going back to `reqwest::Response` shows that we can get the string returned using the method `text()`. So your code now becomes

```rust
let res = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/")
              .await?
              .text()
              .await?;
```

**Update from the comments**: Now the problem is that `Document::from_read` only accepts `std::io::Read` as parameters, and `std::string::String` does not implement that trait, and instead of using a crate like `stringreader` we can simply use `Document::from` as document implements the `From<&'a str>` trait.

And, as with almost everything, there are multiple ways of solving this. You could either

1. Create the Document from the string directly with `Document::from(res)`, or
2. Convert the string to a byte slice, which implements Read, and create the document from that with `Document::from_read(res.as_bytes())`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this approach as well while I was doing some testing.  I got a similar error "the trait 'std::io::Read' is not implemented for 'std::string::String'".  I looked at some of the documentation for Read in the documentation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#implementors  .  The implementor section at the bottom does not show String as an implementor--I'm not sure if those are the only types that can be used with Read since I am still very new to Rust.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now, I blindly assumed that String implements Read. Browsing through the implementors I see `&'a [u8]`, so you could call `as_bytes` on the String

Comment: Or alternatively, instead of `Document::from_read()` use `Document::from(res)` as the Document struct implements the `From<&'a str>` trait as documented [here](https://docs.rs/select/0.4.3/select/document/struct.Document.html#implementations)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ended up converting it to &[u8] and it compiles!

Comment: Great, but alternatively could you try the `Document::from` way? Because converting our string to a byte array throws away any encoding information, which is suboptimal at best

Comment: Tried using Document::from, however, it says trait 'std::convert::From<&std::string::String>' is not implemented for 'select::document::Document".  After looking at the documentation for select (https://docs.rs/select/0.4.3/select/document/struct.Document.html), it looks like the only methods for select::document::Document are "find", "from_read", and "nth".  Could another possible solution be converting the response data to a string then creating a file and passing that to Document::from_read? That does seem extremely suboptimal though as well.

Comment: Very weird, it says there that Document implements `impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Document`. Maybe you need to explicitly convert it like `Document::from(&res[..])` (this takes a full slice of res returning a str) or deref the String like `Document::from(&*res)`. And yes, creating a file and reading that is suboptimal